# Don't understand how Google's infinite load example works

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

Would anyone be willing to explain how the following example works?

http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items

I don't understand how the URL gets updated (changes from /items?page=2 to /items?page=3)

I also do not understand how the rel tags get updated either (prev/next/canonical)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Well the demo script is fully running...I just don't understand it.

Comment: Post your code than,,

Comment: The code is posted in the link

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://scrollsample.appspot.com/static/main.js

and look for the `initPaginator` function. There's a call to `history.replaceState`.

`history.replaceState` allows you to update the address bar without a page change.

Comment: Ahhh...thanks.  Any idea about the rel tags?

Comment: Never seen it before, but it looks like an SEO thing. I don't believe it has any actual consequence in how the app runs. https://yoast.com/rel-next-prev-paginated-archives/